# How do I stop my text overflowing in and HTML div?

Tags: html, css

I have got a pricing table on my website, the design is all good but I cannot get the text in one div to not overflow. I have tried  `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but that doesn't work.
The relevant (or at least what I believe is relevant) HTML and CSS is below. Thanks.

```
<div class="overflow">
  <h2 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-2">Stop Doubting Your Business Idea</h2>
</div>
```

```
.u-text-default {
  display: table;
}
.u-text-default:empty {
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
}
```

I have hosted the whole site on a temporary URL at https://nervous-kare-1f386c.netlify.app/, you will find the issue from "Start now & don't look back.", to the end of the table.
EDIT - I haven't edited any of the text from the pricing table, I have just filled it in with stock text.

Comment: `.u-section-1 .u-text-2` has an assigned width of 534px.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please note, that question on SO need a purpose for the "public". Its not a Forum or Tutorial site. Therefor you need to provide enough code in the snippet to have that error reproduced on this site. If a Site you linking change, then this question would be useless for the "public". SO please edit your Question with enough code to reproduce this error here.

Comment: Did you try to use `&nbsp` 

`Stop&nbsp;Doubting Your&nbsp;Business Idea`

Comment: @tacoshy, I apologies, I see what you mean. I have just started editing it now.

Comment: Is the table supposed to be kept at the same width?

Comment: I fail to see why this has been edited by someone